# Increase a cell's value based on other cell's value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

What I am looking for is an "IF" formula that can solve my problem:

1. I have a single sheet with 2 columns and an unlimited number of rows.
2. On the first column (Column#1), I have a drop-down with only two values: "Option1" and "Option2"; "Option1" is linked to "x" and "Option2" is linked to "y"
3. On the second column (Column#2), I have to give consecutive numbers to each value.

I used this formula on Column#2 ~ **=IF(A14="Option1","x",IF(A14="Option2","y",""))** ~ to offer the ID for each option.

I don't know how to count the values that will have to appear after each value from Column#2.

e.g. - this is how it should look:

Column#1............Column#2

1. **Option1.......x1**
2. Option1........x2
3. **Option2.......y3**
4. Option1........x4
5. **Option2.......y5**

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enterr:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="1","X","Y") & ROW()
```

and copy down:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

and to leave the formula cell blank of the column **A** cell is blank, use:

```
=IF(A1="","",IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="1","X","Y") & ROW())
```

**EDIT#2:**

To start anywhere, say **B5**, use

```
=IF(A5="","",IF(RIGHT(A5,1)="1","X","Y") & ROWS($1:1))
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thank you! But I have one more question: How can I write this formula for the cell to stay blank if neither of the two options is selected in the Colulmn#1 (A column in this case). As a reminder, in the first column I have a dropdown which by default is blank.

Comment: @IonutMares See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: Thank you so much for your time!  The formula works well, but I've encounter other issue. I have on my first row the title of each column, so I can't use the first row. However, I need the counting to start from "1", even if the first entry it will be on row 3 (to be more clear, the third row will have to contain: Option1 / X1 or Option 2 / Y1). It is possible to count in a different way, without using the row number?

Comment: Simply substitute ROW() with ROW()-1 then.

Comment: @IonutMares  See my **EDIT#2:**